# Same permissions for multiple repositories

Tags: gitolite

I have 2 git repos that have permissions looking similar to this:

```
repo    myrepo
    RW+     = admin
    RW user1$       = user1
    RW user2$       = user2
    RW user3$       = user3
    RW user4$       = user4
```

with the number of users being rather high (~100 at the moment) and growing. In order to avoid to maintain the permissions for both lists I was wondering if some sort of inheritance between repos or a looping over users
would be possible (I tried to search the http://gitolite.com/gitolite/#documentation and stackoverflow)

So is it possible to do something similar to configure that `repo2` has the same permissions as `repo1` and/or do the permissions per user/branch in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least, the first thing to consider would be the notion of group of users: you can use one group in both repo, and update the user list for that group once.

See [group definition](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/#group-definitions)

```
@developers     =   user1 user2 user3

repo    myrepo
    RW+     = admin
    RW      = @developer

repo    myrepo2
    RW+     = admin
    RW      = @developer
```

After that, to *really* scale, you could define that group in order to get its content automatically from a [user referential like LDAP](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/#getting-user-group-info-from-ldap).

```
GROUPLIST_PGM           =>  '/home/git/bin/ldap-query-groups',
```

You would then no longer have to modify the `gitolite-admin` repo at all.

---

> what I need is that everyone in the group gets their own branch (with branch name == user name).

That is called ["personal" branches in Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/user/#personal-branches):

> "personal" branches are great for environments where developers need to share work but can't directly pull from each other (usually due to either a networking or authentication related reason, both common in corporate setups).
>
> Personal branches exist in a namespace of their own. The syntax is:

```
RW+ personal/USER/  =   @userlist
```

> where the "`personal`" can be anything you like (but cannot be empty), and the "`/USER/`" part is necessary (including both slashes).
>
> A user "`alice`" (if she's in the userlist) can then push any branches inside `personal/alice/` (i.e., she can push `personal/alice/foo` and `personal/alice/bar`, but NOT `personal/alice`).

Comment: thx! I am aware of groups, but that only works if all in the group should work on the same branch, but what I need is that everyone in the group gets their own branch (with branch name == user name). And the LDAP solution might be great if you already use LDAP, but I really don't want to do that either. If there is no solution to directly do this in the config file, I'll probably just write a bash or python script that adds the same rule to all repos specified...

Comment: @andipla I have edited the answer to address pushing to one own's branch.

Comment: that is perfect -- exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @VonC's excellent answer, you can also group your repos.

```
@developers     =   user1 user2 user3
@cust1repos     =   myrepo myrepo2

repo    @cust1repos
    RW+     = admin
    RW      = @developer
```

This is basically the very first example here http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/